# Nav Tabs or Partial View which one is better?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I have a long form and I am developing an application in ASP.NET MVC. Is it better to have the tabs or should I use partial views and create a new page overall?

-In case if I use the tabs how do I do the validations.
-In case of Partial Views How to I pass the data to next page and how do I store the data till the submit page.

Please let me out. TIA

Answer (score 0):

It's Completely demanding on your **UX Design** to choose which one but I suggest you use **Tabs** because it's more user-friendly. For pass data, I suggest You use **TempData** or **Session** both of Them are useable across multiple controllers and views. To validate the User I suggest You use the **ASP.NET.Identity** package, It has **User.InRole()** and **User.IsAuthorized()** methods to check user accesses.

Comment: How do I validate the first tab form

Comment: To validate the Form , you can use the razor ValidationMessageFor() method I suggest you put all of your entities in one class and declare all of your entities and set your validation attributes, and use this class as the model in this View and use the razor to validate the form. you just need to callValidationMessageFor() it will do validating automatically for you

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have been doing some work around. I have created a form  along with other fileds having validation and there is one field where it doesn't have the validationMessageFor but in validationSummary I am able to see the error for that field and model doesn't have the required property.